# 一度やると言った◯◯、何があってもやりますよ。What should be included in 〇〇?

Tags: jlpt, grammar

This is one of the [JLPT questions](http://wordgrammar.net/japanese-language-proficiency-test-jlpt-n3-grammar-exercise-20/) that I am not sure about (again...).

> 一度{いちど}やると言った◯◯、何があってもやりますよ。
>
> A. からといって　　B. からで　　C. からでないと　　D. からには

For A. からといって, I understand that it can mean "just because" to show that the latter sentence may be differ from what one might expect based on the first sentence, so it is unlikely to be this choice. Though I am curious, if this choice will make sense if the latter sentence become a somewhat negative sentence instead such as

> 一度{いちど}やると言った**からといって**、何があってもやるわけじゃない。

For C. からでないと, I understand that it should follow the pattern ～て form + からでないと + negative sentence, so it is also unlikely to be this choice.

For D. からには, I understand that it implies "now that; because". For  [example](https://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n2-grammar-%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF-kara-niwa/),

> 約束{やくそく}した**からには**その約束{やくそく}を守{まも}らなければならない。

is quite similar to this question, so I believe this should be an appropriate choice (which was correct btw).

However, I am not quite sure why B. からで cannot be used in this case? I know it is simply a continuative form of からだ also implying the cause of something.
Is this because it will **only** explain the cause of the prior sentence?
In order to use B. からで, if I change the sentence into

> 何があってもやるのは、一度{いちど}やると言った**からだ**。

, will this be better?

Answer (score 1):

As you answered yourself, the form of "Aは Bからだ" means "A is because B" and the continuative form "Aは Bからで、C" means "A is because B, so C". So, …言ったからで…やりますよ is an incomplete sentence.